# Posting data using Axios Api in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cors, axios

I tried these code to post data using Axios Api in Vue in I am getting these error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos' from origin 'null' has
>   been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
>   is present on the requested resource. 16_Axios_API_CRUD.html:96 Error:
>   Network Error
>       at e.exports (spread.js:25)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.l.onerror (spread.js:25)

```js
 new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data() {
          return {
            todos: [],
            newTodo: "",
            loading: true,
            errored: false
          };
        },
        methods: {          
          addToDo() {
            debugger;
            const _todo = {
              title: this.newTodo,
              completed: false
            };

            //const { title } = this.newTodo;
            axios
              .post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", _todo)
              .then(res => (this.todos = [...this.todos, res.data]))
          }
        },
        mounted() {
          axios
            .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=5")
            .then(response => (this.todos = response.data))
        }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>

    <div id="app">
      <input
        v-model.trim="newTodo"
      />
      <input
        value="Add"
        type="button"
        v-on:click="addToDo"
      />

      <section v-else>
        <div v-bind:key="todo.id" v-for="todo in todos">
          <div class="todo-item" v-bind:class="{'is-complete':todo.completed}">
            <p>
              {{todo.title}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
```

Anyone face this error message before? Do I need destructor which I notice in some tutorial before posting it? Not quite sure why some tutorial have destructor though.

Edit: It looks like 'slow processing' issue. I can the posted data after a long time. How do I add some 'animation' to show that it is actually in progress posting the data and in progress of returning it back?

Comment: You shouldn't be using absolute URLs. Are you not using a proxy server?  So you can make requests to relative URLs, avoiding this type of problem. More on this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/never-use-an-absolute-path-for-your-apis-again-9ee9199563be/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using absolute URL's. There are two ways you can handle this.

- Configure your server to handle CORS Headers
- Configure a local reverse-proxy using a tool like webpack-dev-server or nginx.

If you choose the second, which is recommended over the other, your code will be like this:

```
axios
          .post("/api/todos", _todo)
          .then(res => (this.todos = [...this.todos, res.data]))
```

And in your reverse-proxy, made possible by webpack-dev-server:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
    },
    secure: true
  }
};
```

More on this:

- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/never-use-an-absolute-path-for-your-apis-again-9ee9199563be/
- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy